# FROM clause of INSERT INTO throwing unhandled exception in VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, unhandled-exception, import-from-csv

I'm running VB 2019, trying to import a CSV file into an Access database using this code:

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + My.Settings.DataLoc + "\PassMan.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + My.Settings.Authentication + ";")
Dim command As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
conn.Open()

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Passwords SELECT * FROM [text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=yes;DATABASE=" + My.Settings.DataLoc + "\PassMan.accdb] AS " + Path.GetFileName(ReadFile), conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

ReadFile is defined by the user as a filename based on an OpenFileDialog. The name of the file I provide at runtime exists. The database file exists and is available, not open by any other app (I've used the same conn code elsewhere in the app).

I get an unhandled exception in the FROM clause in the INSERT INTO statement:

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' System.Exception.InnerException.get returned Nothing.**

What's the problem? How do I solve it? I'm stuck!

Comment: Sql query errors shouldn't result in null reference exceptions. Probably if it is erroring on that line of code it is that the cmd isn't being created successfully, perhaps conn is nothing, or Settings is nothing or Path.GetFileName isn't working ... lots of things to check on!

Comment: Your OleDbCommand command text looks a little off to me, is the a reason you're specifiying the database again, and still passing in the connection string?  Also string concatenation operator for vb.net is & rather than + and you might find it useful reading up on the System.IO.Path.Combine method too

Comment: You are clearly correct, it's the cmd that is not being created correctly. The question is, where. The conn.open command works without an error. I used a messagebox to see if the ReadFile and database files exist just prior to the Dim cmd command, and they do. I substituted the actual text for the ReadFile and Settings command for the database file, and I'm still getting the same messages, even though this is inside a try-catch-finally.

Comment: I took out the reference to the databasde in the OleDbCommand command, and kept the name of the AS file as text so now there are no "+" concatenations. The problem remains:

Comment: I'm also confused as to why you are creating a connection, then putting connection information in the command text - it looks like you are establishing a connection with the text file (?) from the VB code, then also connecting to the text file from Access with the remote query command - but are you are connecting to Access from your VB code?

Comment: These are the problem statements, using text for AS file:    **Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Passwords SELECT * FROM [text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES AS C:\Users\mwulf\Dropbox\Projects\PasswordManager\PasswordManager\DataTemp\6-25-2022PW.csv", Conn)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()**

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment. I did remove the reference to the Access database from the INSERT INTO cmd  OleDbCommand statement, but I still have the same problem. I'm trying to insert values from the 6-25-2022PW.csv text file into my PassMan.accdb Access database. In case you're wondering, there are no spaces in any of these file names.

Comment: what is VB 2019. Is that VB.NET ?

Comment: Yes, VB 2019 is part of Visual Studio with VB.Net. I have abandoned the approach I was using. I'm using TextFieldParser to read the data in from the CSV, then inserting them into Access one row at a time. It's a small spreadsheet and a small database, so it's very fast. And best of all, it works. So far the only problem I have is with fields that contain quotation marks, but that's a minor issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: >  I'm trying to insert values from the _6-25-2022PW.csv_ text
This filename is what you need to use in the second instance you're currently using `DATABASE= [...] PassMan.accdb` instead of  _PassMan.accdb_. Because that is where you configure then *source* file from which you `INSERT INTO` your Access database.

Comment: I believe I found the cause of the error.  When I added the rows one at a time, there was one cell that caused an error which was trapped by my try-catch-end try: the text included a quotation mark ("). As long as I was trapping the error one row at a time, the other values were imported correctly.